# What does "piracy pirates" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, metaphors, word-games

What does the following phrase mean?

> [In Soviet Russia, piracy pirates YOU.](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20110207/00082712982/russian-govt-forced-to-pay-newspaper-editor-it-falsely-accused-piracy.shtml#c40)

What is implied by "piracy pirates YOU" and what by "IN Soviet
Russia"?

**Update 1:** My difficulty was because the term "pirate" and "piracy" are senseless to apply to Soviet Russia because there was no, strictly
speaking, author rights.   Nothing to pirate. Everything is already
belonged by everybody.

@[Ed Guiness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12061/what-does-piracy-pirates-mean/12062#12062),    thanks for the link, I have never heard of them.
At my youth other themes were popular like:

- American to Russian: 'In the USA, I can come to The White House and cry out: "Reagan is a moron"'
- Russian to American: 'I also can come to Red Square and cry out: "Reagan is moron"'

And those in your link are somewhat unknownat my time and even less
now since currently everybody is is quite indifferent to politics.

**Update 2:**  Subjectively, I gave credibility to George Orwell's 1948's
*1984*, rather more universally known and earlier than Yakoff Smirnoff.

Comment: Can't help but think of the Rocky movie where Dolph Lundgren tells him "I must break you" in that thick Russian accent.

Comment: I'll point out that piracy pirates really does mean nothing. They did it for the redundancy. To use another meme "obvious man is obvious"

Comment: How can piracy pirate someone?  "Pirates" is used as a verb, but the phrase is meaningless. It was written by someone blindly applying the meme without caring whether it made sense the way "...radio listens to you" does.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a (rather unfunny, IMHO) variation of the (rather unfunny, IMHO) "In Soviet Russia" meme. The most famous examples are probably "In Soviet Russia, TV watches you!" and "In Soviet Russia, radio listens to you!"

Encyclopedia Dramatica has [more examples](http://encyclopediadramatica.com/In_Soviet_Russia...).

So, what the sentence basically says is, "in all normal countries, you pirate stuff, but Soviet Russia was so backwards that stuff would pirate you".

Answer (score 11):

It's a style of humour originated by Yakov Smirnoff

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakov_Smirnoff#Russian_reversal

For example

In America, you assassinate president.

In Soviet Russia, president assassinate you.

Comment: And it's become an internet meme, which means some people  reflexively repeat it even in ways that make no sense.

Comment: from your answer I understood that it is commonly used in the West but it is rather confusing to hear and understand in Russia.

Comment: Well, in Soviet Russia there was no President, so it is confusing - whose president of which country assasinate Russians.  Besides, as a matter of fact, in the USSR Russia was not formally separate autonomous part (in contrast to other republics). The term Russia was not generally used to refer to any specific part. As such it was used only after desintegration of USSR. So, your phrases is complete nonsense for Russians

Comment: It would not be the first time that memes originating in USA were not understandable by the natives of the place the meme was using for effect.

Comment: PS: One of my favourite cold war jokes had a punch line of "New  skirmishes on the Sino-Finnish border"